# how to create 2 identical lists of objects and how to let operations impact both lists at the same time?

Tags: python, list

Hi I need to create 2 lists that can be manipulated as one:
here when I delete the node with id zero from cluster[0][x], I need it also to be deleted from NODES list. I tried copy() and deepcopy() on python3 and none work either. So I'll greatly appreciate your help.

```
import math
class Node():
    def __init__(self,id):
        self.id=id

class cluster():
    def __init__(self,id=0, Level=0, clusterNodes=[]):
        self.id=id
        self.clusterLevel=0
        self.clusterNodes = []
NODES =[]
cluster0=[]
Dn=5
Gn=2
counter=0 
deviceNodeId = 0
GATEWAYIDS = ['a','b','c','d','e','f']

for i in GATEWAYIDS:
        cluster0.append(cluster(GATEWAYIDS.index(i),0,[]))

for i in GATEWAYIDS:
    for j in range(Dn):
        NODES.append(Node(deviceNodeId))
        cluster0 [math.floor((deviceNodeId)/Dn)].clusterNodes= NODES[Gn+counter:Gn+counter+j+1]
        deviceNodeId += 1
    counter+=j+1
       
for x in range(Gn):
    for node in cluster0[x].clusterNodes:
        if node.id == 0:
            cluster0[x].clusterNodes.remove(node)
          
print('All nodes in NODES look as follows:')
for x in NODES:
    print (x.id)
```

Comment: Then why keep both data structures?  What's the point?  Why can't you just create one from the other when you need it?

Comment: `copy()` and `deepcopy()` do the literal exact opposite of what you want.

Comment: I need 2 different data structures because I will use parts of them differently within my program. Is there a way to get an identical list of 2 lists please ?